# detect if </div> doesn't have opening tag

Tags: javascript, tags, element

I make a `<div id="canEdit">` with an attribute `contentEditable=true` .
below the `#canEdit`, i make a button "Switch to HTML" which will convert the `<div>` into `<textarea>` and it will show up the SOURCE CODE inside the `#canEdit` ..

and it will be a button to convert back into COMPOSE mode...

the problem here is,
when I put extra `</div>` without the opening tag (inside HTML MODE), the code below the `</div>` will be out of the #canEdit's box after switch to COMPOSE MODE

my question is,
how to remove/prevent the `</div>` without the opening tag..

p/s: i am sure in this website also doesn't allow the </div> without the opening tag (or without clicking the code sample), that's why i had to put backslash first before the common slash ( </div> )...if not, the tag will be erase..

so, how to do that..how to erase the `</div>` without opening tag

```
$('#toggleHtmlCompose').click(function(){
        if ($('#tulis').is('div')) {
            tempisi=$('#tulis').html();
            $('#tulis').replaceWith("<div><textarea id=\"tulis\" style=\"text-align:left\">"+tempisi+"</textarea></div>");
            $(this).val("Switch to Compose Mode");
        }
        else if ($('#tulis').is('textarea')) {
            tempisi=$('#tulis').val();
            tempisi=tempisi.replace(/<\/div> *without opening tag*/g,""); // problem
            $('#tulis').parent().replaceWith("<div id=\"tulis\" contentEditable=\"true\" ></div>");
            $('#tulis').html(tempisi);
            $(this).val("Switch to HTML Mode");
        }           
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i just solved it myself...

instead of erase the extra `</div>` , 
i had make an alert saying that "Error! There must be extra </div> in your code" .

```
$('#toggleHtmlCompose').click(function(){
    if ($('#tulis').is('div')) {
        tempisi=$('#tulis').html();
        $('#tulis').replaceWith("<div><textarea id=\"tulis\" style=\"text-align:left\">"+tempisi+"</textarea></div>");
        $(this).val("Switch to Compose Mode");
    }
    else if ($('#tulis').is('textarea')) {
        tempisi=$('#tulis').val();
            var CalcDivOpen=(tempisi.match(/<div/g)).length; //this is the solution
            var CalcDivClose=(tempisi.match(/<\/div/g)).length; //this is the solution
            if (CalcDivOpen!=CalcDivClose) { 
                alert("Error! There must be an extra <div> inside your code. ");
                return false;
            } //this is the solution
        $('#tulis').parent().replaceWith("<div id=\"tulis\" contentEditable=\"true\" ></div>");
        $('#tulis').html(tempisi);
        $(this).val("Switch to HTML Mode");
    }           
});
```

Thank you... haha